# Workaround for casting method parameter interface to desired concrete type in polymorphic design?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say that I have a group of report types to be created and all of them inherit from base abstract class:

```
abstract class Report
{
   public abstract void GenerateReport(IReportData data);

   protected virtual string SaveReportFile(string filepath)
   {
       // common code to save the report file
   }
}
```

`GenerateReport()` method accepts an interface that presents a data object needed for specific type of report and is defined as:

```
interface IReportData
{
    string ReportTitle {get; set;}
    int SomeOtherProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Concrete implementations of reports data classes are as follows:

```
class ReadingsReportData : IReportData
{
    public string ReportTitle {get; set;}
    public int SomeOtherProperty {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> Readings {get; set;}
}

class CalculationReportData : IReportData
{
    public string ReportTitle {get; set;}
    public int SomeOtherProperty {get; set;}
    public int Factor {get; set;}
    public List<decimal> Calculations {get; set;}   
}
```

Now, I have several concrete report classes that should use concrete implementation of IReportData respectively - CalculationReport needs to work on
`CalculationReportData` object and `ReadingsReport` should use `ReadingsReportData` object

```
class CalculationReport : Report
{
   public override void GenerateReport(IReportData data)
   {
       CalculationReportData cdata = data as CalculationReportData; 
       // do something with cdata
   }
}

class ReadingsReport : Report
{
   public override void GenerateReport(IReportData data)
   {
      ReadingsReportData rdata = data as ReadingsReportData;        
      // do something with rdata
   }
}
```

To get to required `ReportData` object for every report type, I have to cast interface to desired concrete implementation class, which is not nice.

What are my options to change the design so that I would not need to perform that cast?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `IReportData` interface?

Comment: pretty sure this was asked recently and the answer is generics

Comment: It defines some basic properties that are required for all reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were me, I would dispense with the `IReportData` interface, and make your abstract class generic:

```
abstract class Report<T>
{
   public abstract void GenerateReport(T data);

   protected virtual string SaveReportFile(string filepath)
   {
       // common code to save the report file
   }
}
```

Comment: `abstract class Report<T> where T : IReport`